# metal shader: pass color encoded as 4 bytes INTEGER instead of 8 Bytes FLOAT

Tags: ios, objective-c, shader, metal, metalkit

I need to send color encoded as in 4 bytes RGBA channel in **INTEGER** (not float) to my metal shader, but I don't know if metal shader can handle color stored in INTEGER. Actually I translate it in the shader to float4 (don't even know if it's not better to use half4 instead) color but I don't know if it's a good way:

```
struct VertexIn {
  packed_float3 pos;
  packed_uchar4 color;
};

struct VertexOut {
  float4 pos [[position]];
  float4 color;
};

vertex VertexOut vertexShader(const device VertexIn *vertexArray [[buffer(0)]],
                              const unsigned int vid [[vertex_id]]){

  VertexIn in = vertexArray[vid];
  VertexOut out;
  out.color = float4(float(in.color[2])/255,float(in.color[1])/255,float(in.color[0])/255,float(in.color[3])/255);
  out.pos = float4(in.pos.x, in.pos.y, in.pos.z, 1);

  return out;

}


fragment float4 fragmentShader(VertexOut interpolated [[stage_in]]){
    return interpolated.color;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 don't understand how you want i could be more specific: how to pass color encoded as 4 bytes INTEGER instead of 8 Bytes FLOAT?

Comment: I don't see why that won't work, but you need to tell us about the pixelformat of the input colour, as the swizzling is likely where you are going wrong.  Otherwise do the conversion on the CPU side and keep it simple.

Comment: Hi @trojanfoe... Actually it's work the code I gave but don't know if it's efficient! Their no way in the shader to work with integer color instead of float color?

Comment: @loki Well you can work with whatever form you like (you demonstrate that), however at the end of the day the colour must be returned from the fragment shader as `float4`/`half4`.  I don't think there are many issues with your code.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks! by the way what to choose for color, float4 or half4 ?

Comment: I normally use `float4`, but I'm sure `half4` will work just as well if the input is 8-bits per-channel given 16-bit floats can represent 0-2048 exactly and the input would only be 0-255.

Comment: I know this question is a bit outdated, but I've stumbled upon similar issue and found a workaround, maybe it's related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66578837/how-to-draw-on-mtltexture-in-bgra8unorm-pixel-format/66637191#66637191