# How to draw on MTLTexture in bgra8Unorm pixel format

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, metal, metalkit

My code works when I draw on `MTLTexture` with `rgba32Float` pixel format, I can take then `CVPixelBuffer` out of it.

But `FlutterTexture` requires `bgra8Unorm` format. I do not want to convert `CVPixelBuffer` due to performance overhead.

So I'm trying to render on `MTLTexture` with `bgra8Unorm` pixel format, but the following fragment shader code won't compile:

```
fragment vector_uchar4 fragmentShader2(Vertex interpolated [[stage_in]]) {
    return 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

With error: `Invalid return type 'vector_uchar4' for fragment function`
I've tried to replace it with `uint` type, but it crashes with error:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
Error Domain=AGXMetalA11 Code=3 
"output of type uint is not compatible with a MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm color attachement."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=output of type uint is not compatible with a MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm color attachement.}
```

If I use `vector_float4` or `vector_half4` return type my texture and buffers are empty.

Which return type I have to use for `bgra8Unorm` pixel format and get non empty image? Is it possible with metal at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found answer on page 30 of [Metal Shading Language specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

[image]

And finally this code draws image as expected:

```
fragment float4 fragmentShader2(Vertex interpolated [[stage_in]]) {
    // ...
    rgba8unorm<float4> rgba;
    rgba = float4(color.r, color.g, color.b, 1.0);
    return rgba;
}
```

If someone can explain what is happening under the hood, I would really like to not waste bounty.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on many different factors. In most cases you should use `float4` or `half4`.

All modern apple GPUs that support metal designed to perform calculation on ( 32-bit or 64-bit) floating point data. It's how GPUs works, this means that any read operation calculated by the shader on the `Float`, `Snorm`, `Unorm` formats will be performed on 32-bit or 64-bit floating point, regardless of the original input format.
On any writing operation shader performs conversion from 32-bit or 64-bit floating point to target format. 
 For conversion rules please see [Metal Shading Language specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) **page 217**.

Any metal formats that use the `Float`, `Snorm`, `Unorm` suffix are floating-point formats, while `Uint` and `Sint` are unsigned and signed integer.

`Float` - A floating-point value in any of the representations defined by metal.

`Unorm` - A floating-point value in range **[0.0, 1.0]**.

`Snorm` - A floating-point value in range **[-1.0, 1.0]**.

`Uint` - A unsigned integer.

`Sint` - A signed integer.

Comment: On which factors it depends? Where I can read about them? Also `float4` doesn't seems correct, because it's 32 bytes instead of single byte